# How far can I jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Fairly frequently, I see a gap in Minecraft that I think I can make, so I go for it...and lose a couple hearts because I didn't.  How far can *you* jump horizontally (or horizontally + 1-3 blocks down), so I know if I'm bad or just ill-equipped (in game).

Comment: If Minecraft uses the real gravity parabola then you can probably make it at most 7 blocks horizontally at a height difference that would almost kill you from falling damage.

Comment: @Sadly Not - Falling damage was answered / discussed here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/how-is-fall-damage-calculated-in-minecraft

Comment: Then you can put this into a nice 'will-I-die?' equation :)

Comment: We have a resident Minecraft code-diver (can't remember their name) that will probably sweep the floor once they find this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read the long explanation of my answer below, but here is a chart that summarizes how big of a gap you can jump along with how far you must fall to make the jump and the damage you will take (without mitigation). You must make a full running jump for this chart to apply:

```
Gap Width (Blocks)  Blocks fallen below jump level  Damage taken from fall
2                   none                            none
3                   2½                              1
4                   7½                              3½
5                   14½                             7
6                   23½                             11½ (death)
```

So without falling damage mitigation you can make a jump over a gap that is at most 5 blocks wide, after falling about 14 blocks down from the point where you make a running jump.

I will test this in-game at a later time to make sure this is realistic.

---

So this answer only works given a number of assumptions hold.

First assumption, Minecraft models gravity using a parabolic equation of the form `y = a(x - h)^2 + k`, where `x` is the size of the gap you want to jump and `y` is the height difference you will be after clearing the gap (negative indicates you are below the point you jumped). `a` is a tunable parameter that describes the rate at which you will fall (related to the constant of gravity). `k` is the highest you can jump from the ground in Minecraft and `h` is the horizontal distance you will have cleared while jumping that high after running forward.

Second assumption, that `k` (the height you can jump from the ground) is 1½ blocks and `h` (the horizontal distance you will have cleared at that height) is 1 block.

Third assumption, that horizontal momentum is preserved. Basically this means that you will travel at the same speed horizontally throughout the jump.

These three assumptions give the equation `y = -(x - 1)^2 + 1½`.

So let's say you want to jump a gap that is 2 blocks wide. To see how far down you must fall before making that jump, plug `x = 2` into the equation and you get `y = ½`. This corresponds with being able to safely jump a gap that is 2 blocks wide with a running jump, and you will reach a block on the other side of the gap while being a little higher than ground level.

[Falling damage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/how-is-fall-damage-calculated-in-minecraft/10219#10219) is calculated as `(number of blocks fallen x ½) - 1½`. So, let's say you want to jump a gap that is 5 blocks wide. Plug `x = 5` into the equation and you get `y = -14½`. This means you will reach jump a gap that is 5 blocks wide after falling 14½ blocks and taking about 7 hearts of damage.

**Sprinting Added**

You can jump significantly further with sprinting; at least three blocks horizontally. This answer assumes no sprinting but I will try to update it ASAP.

Comment: So if this is framed in terms of how long a gap you can jump, the horizontal distance would be `gap (blocks) - player hitbox`?

Comment: I edited the equations and variables in your answer to make them a little easier to read; hope you don't mind @Sadly Not.

Comment: @Kevin Y: Not at all, I didn't know how to do in-line code blocks.

Comment: @Nick T: This is framed in terms of how wide of a gap you can jump in blocks. This considers the fact that you can jump from the back of your player hitbox and land on the front of your player hitbox. The distances are all 'safe', as in if you don't make the jump then probably no one could. I changed the answer to clarify it for you.

Comment: Any information on sprinting available?

Comment: @Ids Not yet at higher heights but the one additional block rule seems pretty consistent regardless of height.

Comment: @Ids With sprinting you can make a 4 block jump.

Comment: @Timtech AFAIK, sprinting in one direction actually gives you a cumulative speed boost, allowing you to clear a 5 block gap with enough run up. [See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qw5dyML-KJE)

Comment: @kkeey I don't think that video can be reproduced without creative because he used a command block to position himself exactly at the right coords to line up for that jump. But it's certainly possible to build enough momentum with headhitting (sprint-jumping with blocks above you) to do a 5-block jump. Check out youtube.com/watch?v=mkmSks-M3tc around 6:15 timestamp to see the explanation for your vid or a little earlier to see him do it legit but with headhitting.

Answer (score 1):

I have done an experiment and these are my results:

Without sprinting, the farthest you can get is 3 blocks if the entire surface is flat. Or if you are jumping up, the max is 2 blocks in length, 1 block in height.

If you are sprinting, the farthest you can reach on a flat platform is 5 blocks in length, but if you are jumping up 1 block in height, the max length is 4 blocks.

Hope you enjoy this!

Comment: This is incorrect - for flat surfaces, sprinting = 4 and walking = 2.

Comment: It is possible to jump up to 8 blocks if you use ice, trapdoors and headhitting.

Comment: If you use more advanced techniques, you can jump up to 14 blocks. https://youtu.be/8MhJNEX-8hc

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't been posted on in awhile, but here is my answer, coming from a person who pretty much only plays Minecraft Parkour:

3 block is not possible without sprinting, however 2 and up 1 is possible with no sprinting.

As for with sprinting, a 3 block onto a trapdoor 2 blocks higher (A 3 up 1.18750) is possible. And a 4 block with 8 layers of snow (4 up 0.8750) is said to be possible, however I can only do 7 (4 up 0.750). If you have HH (Headhitter, or 2 block ceiling) and 2 blocks of momentum, you can make a 5 block or 4 up 1.

Lastly, with speed II, it is possible to do a 5 block and a 4 up 1 if you have momentum.

And just one more thing, you jump 1.20 blocks high without jump boost.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you sprint then you can jump 5 bocks (On a flat surface)
and without sprinting, you can barely get 3

Comment: Welcome to the site! Normally we try to add these kinds of answers as comments to other answers. You will be able to do that if you have enough reputation. Next time try suggesting an edit not an answer. It is an easier way of getting reputation.

Comment: @lds: You make it sound like comments should be suggested as edits instead...

Comment: If you do not have enough rep to add comments, I think it should.

Comment: No, +4x and +1z (4 blocks forward and 1 over) is the max for a flat surface. +2x+1z without sprinting.

Answer (score 0):

Something odd I have found is that you can jump a 3 block diagonal which should be equal to about 4.2 blocks. These seems to bring up the only viable reason being that the game registers the diagonal in Minecraft with a different formula then that of a non diagonal jump, or that the 4 blocks jumping forward is incorrect. I have not yet tested this with partially eaten sides of a cake however which is the easiest way to test the inbetween .5 jumps, or using cords. Lastly I would like to ask if this is a mechanic in the game intentionally designed where it will sort of give you the extra .2 blocks (app).

Answer (score 0):

Almost infinite. Reason?  Give yourself speed 99999999. Using the /effect command.

In actual logic, You can jump 7 blocks without any use of effects, using packed ice, trapdoors, and head hits, to gain enough momentum.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a flat 5 block jump.

I have made a 4x3 jump before in game with no ice/slime/HH/potions/vertical momentum ie a flat 4x3 jump. 4x3 means I am jumping diagonally from the corner of one block to the corner of another block which are 4 blocks of air apart in one direction and 3 blocks of air apart in the other. The gap between these corners is exactly 5 blocks.

I believe the explanation is that since the player has a 0.6x0.6 hit box, you can jump off a block with some of your hit box hanging over the edge of the take-off block and land with only part of your hit box on the landing block. So, the actual distance the player moves is less than 5 blocks.

Despite this, since the distance between the corners of a 4x3 jump is exactly the same as the distance between the edges of a straight 5 block gap, in my opinion, this counts as a 5 block jump.

As a side note, I have not seen anyone make a flat, straight 5 block jump. I don't know why this is. If I had to guess I would say it is because you can overhang your hit box more on the corner of a block than the edge.

Answer (score -1):

You can accually jump 5 blocks. Heres proof :